# Activity View Controller displaying URL in new line

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to display text + Url in single line with UIActivityViewController. But it is displaying URL in new line. I'm using following code

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"Hello:",@" - "];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.raywenderlich.com/84174/ios-8-handoff-tutorial"];

UIActivityViewController *controller =[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",text,url]] applicationActivities:nil];
[controller setValue:@"Hello" forKey:@"subject"];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here is the screenshot attached.
[image]
Any help appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: Probably due to word wrapping? What if you use format like `%@%@` (i.e., remove space) ?

Comment: Yes, it's related to word wrapping. I had done the same thing you have suggested. But No work!!

Comment: @SIVAJEEBATTINA, Update your code. what have you tried yet. remove all the spaces from your string, then it won't wrap your string.

Comment: I am getting the same in single line. iOS version ?

Comment: Please use updated URL and test

Comment: post screenshot please.

Comment: I for one have no such issue as you claimed. Are you sure about your question?

Answer (score 0):

you can do a trick by adding html code inside

```
UIActivityViewController *controller =[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[@"Hello:-  <html><body><a href=\"http://www.raywenderlich.com/84174/ios-8-handoff-tutorial\">link text</a></body></html>"] applicationActivities:nil];
```

NOTE: its not possible to view lengthy URL as it is , but u can do that by another tricky way, by adding space between texts in link as below,

```
UIActivityViewController *controller =[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[@"Hello:-  <html><body><a href=\"http://www.raywenderlich.com/84174/ios-8-handoff-tutorial\">http://www.raywenderlich.com /84174/ ios-8-handoff-tutorial </a></body></html>"] applicationActivities:nil];
```